# Can't override button styles set by user agent

Tags: css, sass

Stuck on this for hours. I'm getting the below whenever I try to set a custom class for buttons, `.btn`. The class works on any `<a>` element, but any button (`<button>` or `<input type="submit">`) inside a form gets ignored. By ignored I mean that in the Chrome dev tools the class isn't even there. `!important` makes no difference, so this isn't a specificity issue. This is weird because the button modifier (I'm using BEM), `.btn--black` is being applied. I'm using SASS, Webpack and React if that makes any difference.

**USER AGENT STYLES**

```
input[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i], 
input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
   border-color: rgb(216, 216, 216) rgb(209, 209, 209) rgb(186, 186, 186);
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   padding: 1px 7px 2px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i], 
input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
align-items: flex-start;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;
color: buttontext;
background-color: buttonface;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 2px 6px 3px;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: outset;
border-color: buttonface;
border-image: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i] {
-webkit-appearance: push-button;
user-select: none;
white-space: pre;
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
background-color: white;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
cursor: text;
padding: 1px;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: inset;
border-color: initial;
border-image: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button {
text-rendering: auto;
color: initial;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
text-transform: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: start;
margin: 0em;
font: 400 11px system-ui;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button, meter, progress {
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you check if the CSS file that's rendered on the browser has the class? Did you do a hard refresh or try using an incognito browser?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks for the tip Praveen, solved now. I just looked at the processed CSS file and realised that I had only written the styles for `btn:link` and `btn:visited`, which were applying fine for `<a>` elements, since those are the default states. Obviously for button elements the `btn` itself also needed those styles, otherwise the browser defaults would apply. Hope this helps someone who ran into the same problem as me.

Comment: @HPJM Awesome. Either please answer this yourself and accept it after two days or please delete the question. Glad that you got it working. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Solved now.

I just looked at the processed CSS file and realised that I had only written the styles for `btn:link` and `btn:visited`, which applied fine for `<a>` elements, since those are the default states.

For `button` elements the `btn` class itself also needed the styles that I had only given to the pseudo-classes, otherwise the browser defaults would apply. Hope this helps someone who ran into the same problem as me.